# Can I access a Google Cloud VM's internal DNS on localhost (through OpenVPN)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openvpn

I have two VM in the same network:

- vpnserver 10.10.0.5
- work-server 10.10.0.6

vpnserver is an openvpn server, after I connect to it I can access work-server on its internal IP (10.10.0.6). I'd like to access it on its internal DNS, like work-server.c.myownproject.internal. Can I push this c.internal domain to my network via openvpn?

Comment: DNS does not push anything except DNS server to DNS server. DNS responds to queries, which means you must forward queries to the DNS server/resolver. Typical client DNS setups do not support split-brain DNS configurations. You can forward all DNS traffic to the VPC, but that would is not recommended (cost, performance, etc).

Comment: @Roberto is your question already answered/resolved? If so, kindly post it as an answer so that other community members with similar questions can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @JohnHanley:

DNS does not push anything except DNS server to DNS server. DNS responds to queries, which means you must forward queries to the DNS server/resolver. Typical client DNS setups do not support split-brain DNS configurations. You can forward all DNS traffic to the VPC, but that is not recommended (cost, performance, etc).